# Trying to achieve this texture

Tags: texturing

Trying to achieve this texture here.
[image: 1][image: 4]

What I have so far.[image: 2]

I would like the "veins" to appear on the inside instead of on the surface, as well as making it translucent, any help would be great![image: 3]

Comment: Hi. What have you tried and where, *specifically*, are you getting stuck?

Comment: Right now I have 2 seperate eggs. one on the inside off the first egg with an image texture of veins I found from google images and the outside egg has subsurface cranked all the way up, low roughness (.25) and transmission is turned all the way up. Also using one more small object for emission on the inside of the first two eggs.

Comment: You should add this extra information to your question using the [edit] link below it, including screenshots of your existing material and node setup. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would have used "veins texture" and blend it with an orange background. Also use Subsurface scattering for the organic look. That's how I would try to make it. Good luck!

Comment: hello, what is "veins texture"? Maybe elaborate a bit

Comment: I don't exactly know what am I looking at in this picture, but It looks like there are some veins in there. Something like this: https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/150-1505458_veins-human-veins-texture-hd-png-download.png

Comment: oh ok I thought you were talking about a procedural texture